# Where do I start with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been coding my PHP applications in Notepad. I want to take it a step up and do it professional, and as far as I can tell using the Zend Framework is where to start. I have been reading the documentation and quick start and a few tutorials but I am still completely lost.

- Is Zend on your local machine or on the remote server?
- Is the "MVC" model different files? A file for the GUI, A File for the Functions used to get data and the database?
- Is there a tutorial that REALLY goes into detail about how you can accomplish things with Zend Framework, and how to get started?

The reason I am asking this is because the tutorials I have been reading still leave me confused and I am very anxious to start doing this professionally. I would like to utilize this new set of tools! Please help :)

Comment: The Zend Framework "Getting Started" tutorial is a good enough intro to the framework if you have a grasp on PHP strong enough to actually need to use a framework to begin with. Do you not use an editor with syntax highlighting?

Comment: I don't use an editor with syntax highlighting. Simply windows notepad. I coded a very complex application for my job though, using MySQL and PHP. I want to make it legit though.

Comment: that last line scares me to no end.

Comment: "I want to make it legit though."? How come?

Comment: Follow the Getting Started tutorial or Akrabats tutorial below and you'll start to understand the terms used and what MVC is - don't worry about the academics for now! I definitely recommend Netbeans 6.5 for PHP - it's free and will provide syntax highlighting, code hints (for ZF too!) and documentation. You can't say fairer than free!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We've all been there before!

Zend Framework is a pretty powerful MVC framework for PHP. There are scads of tutorials all over the net. The quickstart tutorial is good to get a general skeleton of an application, but I found [Akrabat's Zend Framework tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) to be a better real world example.

ZF is fantastic when you're at the point where you need to develop robust applications and need a whole suite of libraries to accompany this - ZF's library is huge and all the components play quite nicely with each other (although, you can rip them out individually and add them to any project). The downside to ZF is that because it is so flexible, there can be quite a bit of complexity in setting it up.

To be honest, if starting to get your feet wet with MVC applications, you might try something a little bit more straight forward. I find [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) to have a very short learning curve while maintaining the fundamentals of MVC design. [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) also walks you through the steps quite deliberately.

Comment: I can simply make an MVC model on my own? From my understanding this is just a way of delivering and separating programming code from styling code. I think a framework is a little excessive because from my understanding, it also includes a library. And I still prefer to code my functions on my own. Do you think this is the right way to go?

Comment: Chris -- it's really hard to say without knowing what the scope and purpose of your project is, but I will say usually it's not the right answer to make your own MVC model -- you're now spending cycles developing something that's probably already done better by someone else. You're probably better off learning a simple framework like CodeIgniter and running with that. 

All frameworks expect that you will code functions on your own, they just lay the environment for you to do so.

Comment: @Chris: a framework is a kind of library.  nobody will 'code your functions for you', using a library is just choosing not to reinvent the wheel.  if you don't like existing wheels, then be free not to use them; but that certainly means not using a framework.  (or maybe writing your own framework)

Comment: Don't worry about not having enough left to do with ZF - you'll still need to hook things together and write bits that the library doesn't have. That said, definitely don't waste time writing functions that already exist - ZF provides robust, unit (and time!) tested functions that work without you having to worry.

You can use as much or as little of the framework as you like, if you're not happy with the MVC stuff you could simply use the Zend_Db component on it's own. There's no lock in or commitment.

Answer (score 10):

The quickstart tutorial is a great way to begin, maybe read it again? There's also this one:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/zend-framework-php-tutorial.html

From the above link:

> This tutorial is intended to give a
>   very basic introduction to using the
>   Zend Framework to write a very basic
>   database driven application.

And here's a list of ZF tutorials for beginners:

**Introduction and database
Tutorial:** http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

Source Files [here](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/zf-tutorial-174.zip)

**Authentication
Tutorial:** 
http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/

Source Files [here](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/zf-auth-tutorial-200.zip)

**Forms
Tutorial:** http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_form-example/

Source Files [here](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Zend_Form_Example.zip)

**File Upload
Tutorial**: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_form-file-upload-example-revisited/

Source Files [here](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Zend_Form_FileUpload_Example.zip)

**Layout
Tutorial:** http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_layout-example/

Source Files [here](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Zend_Layout_Example.zip)

I would make sure they're not for much earlier versions of the ZF before diving in.

Comment: File Upload Tutorial points to a dead link.

Answer (score 4):

[zendcasts.com](http://zendcasts.com) is doing very good Zend Frameword casts. It's really a good place to start.

Comment: It's a good resource, but not exactly "the best place to start." It is worth diving into for intermediate to advanced Zend developers. +1 for the additional resource, though.

Answer (score 2):

> - Is Zend on your local machine or on the remote server?

Zend is PHP code, therefore it runs on the webserver.

Comment: Not necessarily, since you can make use of it from the command line aswell, say for automated scripts that need to make use of Zend_Mail.

Answer (score 2):

Professionally written PHP applications do *not* require a framework. Frameworks exist for people that have been doing some of the same repetitive tasks *repetitively* and desire to change their own workflow.

You should start by researching the "MVC design pattern" in general (as it applies to many things outside of PHP) and get deeper into the concepts of Professional PHP before starting with such a large framework as Zend Framework.

Use a framework because you know you *need* to, and not for any other reason.

Comment: Frameworks are also codified solutions to problems in context, so unless you know the context (which you only discover by having suffered through it), the framework will never be the best choice.

Comment: Where might I be able to find some resources for this? Should I implement an MVC model for my applications? Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial is definitely worth a look, as it walks you through the creation of a fully-functioning web application using ZF 1.8 (at time of writing). The author also updates it each time new versions of the ZF are released.

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [official webinars](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework). Very easy to digest and a requirement for a beginner.

Comment: +1 for the additional resource.