# Zend Framework Resources

Tags: zend-framework

im a beginner to Zend Framework!
i want resources for learning,tutorials and etc. for ZF.
is there anybody here to help me? :)

Comment: -1 for asking before searching SO.

Comment: +1 to reset -1 for a beginner asking a question is a bit harsh. Especially without providing links.

Try to be helpful... We all started as beginners.

To the OP, in addition to Rob Allen's answer, try checking out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952056/where-do-i-start-with-zend-framework

They have a few people with some extra ideas there. Good luck man.

Comment: Well, this -1 was a virtual one ;) I posted a link too, but I can't see it now. Here is once again: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zend+framework+resources I have answered thiw question three times already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html
- http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial
- http://www.zendcasts.com
- http://devzone.zend.com/
- http://www.survivethedeepend.com/

and, of course:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the mailinglist:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/

this blog:

http://zendguru.wordpress.com/

the zf snippets:
http://www.zfsnippets.com/

the zf forums:
http://www.zfforums.com/

the tutorials (some are very old, some are useless, few are helpfull):
http://www.zftutorials.com/

... and my website :) which is pretty new and doesn't have a lot of content, but i will add more during the next weeks / month ;)
http://www.chris.lu