# Zend Framework Codes

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework

what is below codes for?(in Zend Framework)
i mean what is the job of these?

```
$this->view->default
$this->view->action
```

Comment: It coud be anything. Probably `$this->view` is a `Zend_View` object and two variables `action` and `default` are assigned to it. Do you have any more code to see the actual context of this code?

Comment: thank you Felix,i got the point
i was just confused with some basics!
im a beginner

Comment: Then you should read the reference guide: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/ :)

Comment: thank you again felix,i read that book.but it is not something that you can learn from it,it is JUST a REFERENCE!
i need some TUTORIAL

Comment: What about the quickstart: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Answer (score 0):

this question might help you:
[Zend Framework Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808812/zend-framework-resources)

the code you have in your questions is used to path an object to the view, in your controller you do:

```
$this->view->aStringPassedToView = 'foo';
```

and then in your view script you could for example echo the data that got passed like this:

```
echo $this->aStringPassedToView; // prints 'foo'
```