# Zend Framework for Absolute Beginners?

Tags: zend-framework

Can you recommend any book or other resources for learning Zend Framework for absolute beginngers with moderate PHP skills.
Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you use the search before posting this? Possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808812/zend-framework-resources and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456/can-you-recommend-a-good-book-on-zend-framework. BTW You will need a solid knowledge of PHP to really understand the framework, I wouldn't recommend using it for "absolute beginners".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, the three definitive ZF Getting Started tutorials are:

1. [Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) from Zend
2. [Album tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) from Rob Allen
3. [Surviving the Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) from Padraic Brady

Two additional applications which I have found helpful, though a little more advanced, are:

1. Dasprid's blog ([src](http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk)), from Ben Scholzen
2. [PHPPlaneta](https://github.com/robertbasic/phpplaneta), from Robert Basic

Learned a lot from all of them.

And, of course:

[ZendCasts](http://www.zendcasts.com/)

In the end, [Rob Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808812/zend-framework-resources) says it all.

Comment: Some good resources +1. Zend is not the best documented and sometimes the documents are far behind the current release. You covered all the ones I can think of though.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for the edit, Rob. ;-)

Comment: Hey everybody,
I started to learn Zend too a few days ago with the quickstart tutorial. After that I started the Rob Allen tutorial and I have to say, for beginners...it is much better. So I RECOMMEND to all total beginners to get in with the ROB ALLEN Guide.
Here all the important basic stuff is very well explained and after that you wiull have a great basic to get through the quickstart tutorial.

Comment: Sadly, Dasprid's blog is no longer publicly available via svn. https://twitter.com/DASPRiD/status/444627073160986624

Answer (score 3):

[Survive The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) is a good resource to start with a concrete project.

Answer (score 0):

I just started 4 days ago to use Zend Framework together with Doctrine ORM. 
To be honest it's very complicated to get started with it. I used the zend documentation,
http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/ for example the quick start guide. 
There is an irc channel on freenode #zftalk@irc.freenode.net 
In addition I googled a lot, there are some good answers here on stack overflow. 
Sometimes it is good to search for "[what you wanna do] tutorial" this way you get quicker solutions, because the manual often does not give you the general overview, it just explains one or some components.

Answer (score 0):

You can reffere below link for detail study of how zend frameworks basics work.

http://wiki.zf2notes.googlecode.com/git/zf2_beginners_tutorial.wiki