# How to get started with zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to the zend framework and I don't know how the flow of execution works. I am using zend framework version 1.11.8 and wamp server.
My code is:

```
echo 'hello';
$cache  = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
$frontendOptions = array(
  'lifetime' => 10,
  'automatic_serialization' => true);

$backendOptions = array(
  'cache_dir' => 'tmp/'
);
$start_time = microtime(true);

if(!($data = $cache->load($id)))
{
  echo "Not found in Cache<br />";

  $data = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
    {
      $data = $data . $i;
    }
  $cache->save($data);
```

Can anyone help where to place this code and how to run this code?

Comment: You should really work on the titles of your questions... There is a difference between a headline and introductory text, you know?

Comment: Your question shows that you don't know enough about ZF to do what you're doing. It's gonna be really hard to answer it because there is no clear answer. Furthermore 'how to run this code' is a non-question. I mean, how do you run code? So, please try to be more specific. What have you tried, what error messages did you get, etc.

Comment: @curise: Welcome to SO! It's a great community and a gold-mine of information. But, as you can see, the community generally has an expectation that questions will be somewhat more targeted and reflect a bit more initiative before asking. In particular, I think you would do well to check out various ZF quick start guides before throwing out such a general question. Still, I'll give you a quick answer that offers some options. Again, welcome to SO! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using the ZF merely as a component library, then you could just place the `Zend` folder someplace on your PHP `include_path`, register a [PSR-0 autoloader](https://gist.github.com/2006895), and drop this code into a file (say, `mycode.php`). Then you could run from command line using `php mycode.php`.

However, if you are using the ZF as a full-fledged MVC application framework, then you probably need to check out some of the various "getting started" guides. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5340456/131824) for a list of "getting started" resources.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with ZF(Zend Framework) is that before you wanna use it you have to understand at least the basics of it... If you don't understand something then better to start learning, and understand it, because thats the only way:)

When I learned ZF I wrote myself a "diary" to cover the main line how "learned" ZF. This site contains links, and other resources. My english is not the best but hope you will find it useful:  http://zendframeworknewbie.wordpress.com/