# layout.phtml issue in zend framework1

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
$this->headTitle('Zend Framework Tutorial');
echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Above code is taken from this tutorial: `http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf`  it is on page 10, file is : `zf-tutorial/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml`

Question:

1. what is this line for? `$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');`
2. why we need this line: `<?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?>` I guess 'escape' is for security, but what does it actully mean here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342333/131824 for a list of entry-level tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$this->escape()`**

By default, the escape() method uses the PHP htmlspecialchars() function for escaping. [Escaping Output](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.escaping)

**$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');**

When you add multiple values to a headtitle `setSeparator` will seperate the title with the specified seperator.[Head Title](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle)

```
<?php
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$this->headTitle($request->getActionName())
     ->headTitle($request->getControllerName());
$this->headTitle('Zend Framework');   
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
?>
```

`<?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>` will create `<title>action - controller - Zend Framework</title>`