# issue with some codes in zend framework1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am following this tutorial:Getting Started with Zend Framework 1.11

> http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

, on page 12, "Listing albums"

1. `D:\program files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application\models\DbTable\Albums.php`

   ```
   <?php

   class Application_Model_DbTable_Albums extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

       protected $_name = 'albums';

       public function getAlbum($id)
       {
           ...
       }
       public function addAlbum($artist, $title)
       {
       ...
       }

       public function updateAlbum($id, $artist, $title)
       {
           ...
       }
       public function deleteAlbum($id)
       {
           ...
       }


   }
   ```

---

2. `D:\program files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application\controllers\IndexController.php`

   ```
   <?php

   class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action  
   {
       public function indexAction() 
       $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
            $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
       }    
   }
   ```

---

3. `D:\program files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml`

   ```
    <?php
    $this->title = "My Albums";
    $this->headTitle($this->title);
    ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index',
    'action'=>'add'));?>">Add new album</a></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($this->albums as $album) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($album->title);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($album->artist);?></td>
    <td>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index',
    'action'=>'edit', 'id'=>$album->id));?>">Edit</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index',
    'action'=>'delete', 'id'=>$album->id));?>">Delete</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
   ```

---

**Questions:**

1. Albums.php, why we need this one: `protected $_name = 'albums';`?
2. IndexController.php

   a.  `$albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();` we did not use include/require "Albums.php", how could we use thi class:`Application_Model_DbTable_Albums`?

   b. `$this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();` what does this mean: `$this->view->albums`? why not use `$this->albums`?
3. index.phtml

   a. `$this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'))`, where can I check this method: `$this->url()`?

   b. why we use `foreach($this->albums as $album)` here? not `$this->view->albums` as in  IndexController.php?

Comment: Learn php first then move to zend...Zend is not for beginners..IT will be good if you make your concepts strong .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342333/131824 for a list of entry-level tutorials. Also http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Albums.php, why we need this one: protected $_name = 'albums';?

When using a DbTable model in Zend Framework (`Application_Model_DbTable_Albums`) the protected member `$_name` must be the name of the database table that the model is associated with. The DbTable model will in effect become the database adapter for that one table.

> $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums(); we did not use
>   include/require "Albums.php", how could we use thi
>   class:Application_Model_DbTable_Albums?

Classes and files that conform to the expected naming conventions and belong to predefined resources are automatically autoloaded by [Zend_Loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.html). The class `Application_Model_DbTable_Albums` and the file `Application/Model/DbTable/Albums.php` both conform to the naming conventions and belong to a predefined resources.

> $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll(); what does this mean:
>   $this->view->albums? why not use $this->albums?

`$this->view->albums = $ablums->fetchAll();` is a shorthand way of assigning the values obtained from `$albums->fetchAll()` to the [Zend_View object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.html) for display in the view script. The values can be echoed in the view script as `echo $this->albums` or more likely they can be looped with a foreach and then displayed.

> $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add')), where can I
>   check this method: $this->url()?

This is actually a little hard to pin down easily, you'll find a basic definition in the [Zend_View helper reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial), just scroll down until you see it. A somewhat better example can be found in the [Zend_Controller reference router section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html). Essentially the `url()` helper is the preferred method of creating a link in the view script, it is not the only method and sometimes not the best.

> why we use foreach($this->albums as $album) here? not
>   $this->view->albums as in IndexController.php?

in  the controller we assign data to the view object `$this->view->data = $data` in the view script (index.phtml) we are in the view object so we just need to access the supplied data `<?php echo $this->data ?>`. In the case of `$this->albums` the data is a rowset object (an array of Zend_Db_Row objects) which can be iterated using a foreach loop. Most valid data types can be assigned to the view using this method.

This is a pretty simple overview of these concepts, I hope it helps.