# How to configure Zend Framework on linux machine?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to configure Zend Framework on linux machine?

Comment: *(reference)* http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html

Comment: why so down votes? this may discourage the freshers from using stack overflow.

Comment: @Mithun P: I expect that most downvotes are inspired by the fact that there's a giant green column [on the Zend Framework front page](http://framework.zend.com/) titled "Getting Started."  I admit to being blind to things sitting right in front of me, but sometimes questions like this can be completely ridiculous.  That being said, because there's a good answer in here now, I'm giving a pity upvote in the (surely false) hope that someone will find the question and answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good entrypoints in the official Zend Framework Documentation.

- [Installaion](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html)
- [Learning Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.html)
- [Zend Framework Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html)

Especially the "Zend Framework Quick Start" is a good place to start.

Also checkout this Questions on stackoverflow

- [Can you recommend a good book on zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456/can-you-recommend-a-good-book-on-zend-framework)
- [Where do I start with Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952056/where-do-i-start-with-zend-framework)

Answer (score -2):

first download **xampp 1.7.1** with **php 5.2.*** because zend don't support 5.3 yet.
after download it use this site to install it

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

there are many tutorial to how to install it on linux:

http://cyberciti.biz/tips/zend-framework-php-tutorial.html

http://hellosystemadmin.com/blog/how-to-install-zend-frame-work-on-a-linux-and-test-it/

I hope that this might help

Comment: Zend recommends the most current release of PHP for critical security and performance enhancements, and currently supports PHP 5.2.4 **or later**.

Comment: Zend Framework is running fine on php 5.3.