# Why can't I configure Zend-framework

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, configuration

Racking my head as to why I can't include the Zend-framework into my project. The documentation is unclear about how to set up the environment (Or haven't found where it is). Looked at this thread: [How to configure Zend Framework on linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334884/how-to-configure-zend-framework-on-linux-machine-closed) but no luck. In the phpinfo() I see Zend configured but why can't I use it? Looked for documentation on how to add this to PEAR/PECL, no luck.

I did see this post: http://devzone.zend.com/article/4683 but still not working

What I have tried:

## Option 1

```
require_once('/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

## Option 2

```
sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

changed this line:

```
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

to:

```
include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php"
```

restarted Apache

Getting this error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php on
 line 24

Call Stack:
    0.0002      61600   1. {main}() /var/www/webservice/zend/server.zend.xmlrpc.php:0
    0.0009     174412   2. require_once('/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php') /var/www/webservice/zend/server.zend.xmlrpc.php:2


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-p
hp/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php on line 24

Call Stack:
    0.0002      61600   1. {main}() /var/www/webservice/zend/server.zend.xmlrpc.php:0
    0.0009     174412   2. require_once('/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php') /var/www/webservice/zend/server.zend.xmlrpc.php:2
```

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest to

`chmod 775 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php -R` as Ran BarZik suggestion . 
and double check the apache user's  permissions .

then symlink it to the your application library by using this :

```
ln -s /var/www/webservice/library/Zend  /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/
```

Comment: interesting idea, I might try this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, This ended up working the best for me. Now it's just trying to get the service working

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

I;ve installed Zend FW on many Linux system and if I encountered problems it was on the include path that was set incorrectly or permission problem.

Maybe the path isn't right, try 'vi /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' or any other text editor that you like. Does it work?
Maybe it is permission problem, try to change /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/ to 755:

```
chmod 775 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php -R
```

Comment: Thanks I have validated the path and it's correct as well as the permissions are 775 with root:my user as the owner.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Your main configuration should be in: application/configs/application.ini

This tells the zend controller where to look for the library files etc.

Did you look here when you were installing? : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

According to the error messages, your updated include_path isn't being picked up.

What does phpinfo() have to say about your include_path?

What if you `set_include_path(get_include_path .  ':/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php');` before your include?

I'm assuming here that /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend exists...

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Try to move zend library:

```
cd /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php
mv library/Zend /usr/share/php/
```

revert `include_path` to original:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

Restart apache

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense for me to do but it's an option that I will keep in mind, thanks

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head up against the wall for a couple of days I think I figured it out. Looking at this page: http://devzone.zend.com/article/4683 I understood I needed to add the zend path in the php.ini file. I did this with no effect. After looking at my PHP Configuration I noticed in /etc/php5/conf.d/ I could load zend by uncommenting the library path in the zend-framework.ini file which PHP loads as an additional module/ini