# Creating a forum in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to this zend platform and i wish to develop a forum in zend.
Can anyone please help me in developing the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. Start with creating new project.

Seriously: try to be more specific in your question

Comment: u shld give more details. what exactly u need? help on?

Comment: Actually i wish to develop a forum like MyBB in zend but as i am new to this framework i am not getting the way to design the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a forum is too difficult for you to conceptualise I recommend you find some other project to learn the framework. 
Go read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952056/where-do-i-start-with-zend-framework) then you might have a better understanding of the framework and how to use it to create a forum.

Otherwise you know you need to use Zend_Db for your database needs Zend_Acl for your user management needs and a whole bunch of other cool zend libraries.